# Can't seem to find bootstrap.css file

Tags: css, spring, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea, jboss

I'm trying to include `bootstrap.css` in my jsp page. I have a Spring-MVC project deployed on a JBoss 8 application server and my folder structure looks like this: `expenses-spring/src/main/webapp/resources/css/bootstrap.css` in Intellij 14.

With my previous projects I can reach the css file when including it like this in my head: `<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css'/>`. However here this does not seem to work, any idea what I did wrong?

I was thinking that maybe it has something to do with adding a resource handler? I'm not entirely sure what this does:

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/WEB-INF/resources/");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your resource handler configuration is incorrect. If you have resource files in `src/main/webapp/resources/` the resource handler configuration should look like this:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Comment: Aha yes you're correct, my resources were in the WEB-INF folder before but I moved them from there because I thought it might not be a good idea to put resources under protected access